# How to keep a view the same size in React Native when display size changes?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Our app includes a screen where there is a large circle in the background which changes position. It's mostly absolute positioning using this sort of style. The circle changes to use the right style and animates into the new position underneath some tutorial text.

```
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('screen')
const circleRadius = isIphoneX() ? height * 0.55 : height * 0.60

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  circleMassiveLeft: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: primary,
    width: circleRadius * 2,
    height: circleRadius * 2,
    borderRadius: circleRadius,
    left: -circleRadius + width - 50,
    top: -circleRadius + height / 2
  },
  circleMassiveRight: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: primary,
    width: circleRadius * 2,
    height: circleRadius * 2,
    borderRadius: circleRadius,
    left: -circleRadius + 50,
    top: -circleRadius + height / 2
  }
})
```

This has been working great to display the circle in the correct position across multiple display sizes. Since it needs to be so precisely positioned, using absolute positioning seems to be a better solution than flex in this case. **Our challenge is that when changing the system settings in Android to display size small, the circle becomes smaller.** Of course, that makes sense in a way, but this particular element looks pretty awful because of the layout of the rest of the screen when it's resized to be smaller. Elements that used to be on top of it are now poking out! Is there a way to make sure that this element displays at the same size regardless of Android system display size settings? Poking around the docs, there doesn't seem to be a basic setting for this.

Comment: Is this happening when you open your app, change the display size to small, and then go back? Is it also happening when you open the app for the first time? If the former is true and the latter is not, then it sounds like the issue is that when your code is statically setting the size once instead of reacting to size changes. Try using `Dimensions.addEventListener` to react to size changes.

Comment: It happens both times even on a cold start. I had the same thought, so I checked. I might recheck again to be sure

Answer (score 0):

Try to use www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-responsive-dimensions

Answer (score 0):

[read this](https://medium.com/react-native-training/scaling-react-native-apps-for-tablets-211de8399cf1)

In the article they using: [react-native-size-matters](https://github.com/nirsky/react-native-size-matters)